# Python Json - KeyError

Tags: python, json, keyerror

I am trying to retrieve the records from an API and eventually want to store them in a dataframe so that I can do some analytics. But I am getting the following error:

```
  for item in json_obj["records"]:
KeyError: 'records'
```

Code:

```
import urllib.request
import json

import urllib.request
url = 'https://eservices.mas.gov.sg/api/action/datastore/search.json?resource_id=7f1363cc-3875-4e03-a389-fc47342bb840&limit=5'

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('UTF-8')
json_obj = json.loads(response)

for item in json_obj["records"]:
    print(item[end_of_month'])
    print(item['preliminary'])
    print(item['cards_main'])
```

Comment: OK, so there isn't a `'records'` key in the `json_obj` dictionary. Beyond that, what do you think anyone can tell you? Do you know what keys it *does* have? Have you tried printing them out? Doing any other [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: As jonrsharpe said, take a look at what keys there actually are: `console.log(Object.keys(json_obj))` should make it easy to see.

Comment: Peeking at the data, you want `json_obj["result"]["records"]`

Comment: @RichardDunn right idea, wrong language!

Comment: @jonrsharpe oh dear. That's what working in both all day and then staying up late gets me. `print(json_obj.keys())` in that case... Or better still, what I use to explore data in python: `from pprint import pprint` then simply `pprint(json_obj)`

Answer (score 1):

When you cannot find a key where the API doc says that it should be there, you should just print the text of the json, because it is a text format.

Here, it would be evident that the `records` key does exist but is not a top level one but a sub-key of `result`.

Your code should be:

```
for item in json_obj["result"]["records"]:
    print(item['end_of_month'])
    print(item['preliminary'])
    print(item['cards_main'])
```

Comment: Thank you Serge. This solved the problem. I didn't know that I have to use ["result"]["records"] instead of just ["records"]